# Problem with Accounts. Please Advise

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am actually [Ruut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/11343/ruut).

However...

That e-mail account was hacked by someone from China (literally) that I used to log-in with that account; I made a new account just so I could ask new questions (as [Zangief](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29953/zangief)).

---

What on earth can I do? Can I combine my accounts? Can a moderator combine the accounts? Is my reputation as "Ruut" forever gone? Help.

Comment: Apologies, I gave you a Contact link that was attached to meta. Please use the updated link. Or, just go to the main site and find **contact us** at the bottom of the page, in the footer, and use that.

Answer (score 6):

### Mods can't merge accounts

We can't fix this for you, because account merging is a power that SE doesn't give to moderators. Account merges can only be done by SE employees.

To ask for an account merge you need to skip meta and [contact Stack Exchange directly via their contact form.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/contact) (That link takes you directly there. You can always find that link as “**contact us**” on the main site, in the footer.) They don't process merge requests on meta. Once you contact them, they'll work with you to get your accounts merged.

Next time though, don't wait six months! This doesn't take long and could have been resolved long ago.

Comment: I shouldn't have waited. You're right. But... I have an alibi - Uncle Sam tells me to work here, and work there; I don't always have the best of internet connections.

Comment: It's true, but you've been posting as Zangief since July. I understand being busy — but it does seem unnecessary to be active as another account for so long before bringing it up. In any case, that won't matter though: SE will verify ownership through concrete details rather than appearances.

Comment: I will also add, I've been arguing with Google back and forth for a very long time. I will officially say my prior email is dead and buried. That's still not a real excuse; I know.

Comment: Welcome back. :-)

Comment: @Zangief Have you contacted Stack Exchange via the contact form yet?

Comment: @Zangief I noticed you recently lamented that we haven't merged your accounts yet. I just want to make it clear that mods *don't* have the power to do account merges, so we haven't yet because we literally can't. You have to contact SE directly yourself via the contact form. We also can't do that for you. I've updated the answer to say that as clearly as it can. Can you give that a try?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's been over a year. Nothing worked. I gave up.